# Find maximal value for field in all collections

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an database containing collections, and these collections containing documents on the form:

```
{ "_id" : 4, "value" : 2 }
```

I want to find the maximum `"_id"` in all the collections in a efficient way. At the moment, I have a working method:

```
public long getLastTimestamp()
{
    var tempList = getChannelNames();
    var channelList = new List<IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>>();
    var docuList = new List<BsonDocument>();

    foreach (var channel in tempList)
    {
        channelList.Add(_database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(channel.name));
    }

    foreach (var channel in channelList)
    {
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("_id");
        var result = channel.FindAsync(filter).Result.ToList();

        foreach (var docu in result)
        {
            docuList.Add(docu);
        }
    }

    var timeList = new List<long>();

    foreach (var docu in docuList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(docu);
        if (!docu["_id"].IsObjectId)
            timeList.Add(docu["_id"].ToInt64());
    }

    return timeList.Max();
}
```

It works, but I don't think it's very efficient.
Does anyone have some input or advice?

EDIT:
I ended up doing this:

```
    public long getLastTimestamp()
    {
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("value");
        return getChannelNames()
            .Select(channel => _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(channel.name))
            .SelectMany(channel => channel.FindAsync(filter).Result.ToList())
            .Max(docu => docu["_id"].ToInt64());
    }
```

Comment: You could at least combine your first two `foreach` loops.

Comment: Ah, yes. Silly of me not to :P Fixed!

Comment: The last two loops can be combined also. Adding items to a list inside a loop, only to loop over this new list again later, is unnecessary.

Comment: The 2 answers are good about code writing but I think you have some architecture problems.
The strength of MongoDB is that you can put many kind of data in a single collection. if you need to get the highest ID, it means they're linked, the I think it would be better to merge the data in a single collection and just use a property to give them their kind.
for example, type:"Message"
but if you have a specific requirement, these answers are good.
Of course, if you merge the code, you will be able to get the result with only 1 simple query.

Comment: @Demonia You are correct about that the "_id" 's is connected. The database contains information about sensors, and the "_id" 's are timestamps for when the sensors sent their values.

Comment: @DidrikGalteland then I think that with a small architectural rework, you will be able to reach much better performance and probably make your code smaller and easier to read.
Anyway, if you have this specific requirement, you already have good answers ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

```
public long getLastTimestamp()
{
    //var tempList = getChannelNames();
    var channelList = new List<IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>>();
    var docuList = new List<BsonDocument>();

    foreach (var channel in getChannelNames())
    {
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("_id");
        var result = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(channel.name)
                     .FindAsync(filter).Result.ToList();

        return result.Where(x => !x["_id"].IsObjectId)
               .Max(entry => entry["_id"].ToInt64);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Couldnt test it as these objects arnt available to me. On the linq-part you would maybe have to convert to list or array to get `Where()` and `Max()` available.

Storing and iterating again is always slower.

```
public long getLastTimestamp()
{
    var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("_id");

    return getChannelNames()
    .Select(channel => _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(channel.name).FindAsync(filter).Result.ToList())
    .Where(doc => !doc["_id"].IsObjectId)
    .Max(doc => doc["_id"].ToInt64);
}
```

Comment: Linq doesn't means better performances. you can check the code of these extensions and you'll see that it's usually not so good because they manage more use case then more code is executed.

Comment: @Demonia agreed. But it sure is more performant than copying collection three times.

Comment: @Demonia I havnt used linq just because of thinking it will provide a better performance. The original one had a `foreach` at this point which was saving data to a temp list in case of a condition. Going with linq to get on the condition + getting the max value was the right thing I thought without saving anything temporarily.

Comment: But sure, I can just leave out the saving part fully. Editing.

Comment: By using your last edit, in the .Where(doc => !doc["_id"].IsObjectId), VS is telling me that doc can't be converted to string from int. but It's clearly a BsonDocument.. any input? :)

Comment: Oooh, nvm, doc is a list of bsonDocuments

Comment: Right. Doc ist at this point a list. Return type defined as string?

Comment: @DidrikGalteland I also wondered about that you did that in your code didnt you?

Comment: No, when I do it at "docu["_id"]", docu is a BsonDocument, which acts like a normal Json object. use bsonObject[key] to get the key's value.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("_id");

getChannelNames()
    .SelectMany(channel => _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(channel.name))
    .SelectMany(channel => channel.FindAsync(filter).Result.ToList()) // Even better w/o ToList
    .Where(docu => !docu["_id"].IsObjectId)
    .Max(docu => docu["_id"].ToInt64());
```

Comment: getChannelNames atm returns a list of string. Should I change the method to return something else?

Comment: It should work with string just right. Select and SelectMany transform your input data to whatever type you return in lambda function. So when first SelectMany executes, you will have collection of channel names (strings I guess). Second will return collection of BsonDocuments. Where will work with those documents and Max will then calculate max value of document id's. This might need some casting or ToArray, ToList calls but idea is the same.

Comment: Just to explain what I did. I used SelectMany where you used foreach+Add to unwrap collection directly and then use that collection to pipe data to next query.

Comment: Your `ToList()` shouldnt be there shouldnt it?

Comment: @C4u It would be great if it wouldn't, but I don't know what the result value is so maybe ToList is required... Didrik would know

Comment: My bad. You are right. Every result gets saved into a list. It's clearly visible from his code.